# service call - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, web-services

I am trying to get a JSON object from a Webservice and bind to the view. Am able to get the data when i read from the local json but not from the Webservice call.

```js
angular.module('MyCard1App', [ ]).
controller('IndexViewController' , function ($scope, $http) {
//$http.get("data/data.json")
$http.get("http://localhost:9090/service/readerApp/Entity/1234567880?type=Activity&appId=1&userid=test")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.outages = response;});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>taskID</th>
                <th>categoryID</th>
                <th>category</th>
    <th>description</th>
    <th>status</th>
    <th>title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="listItem in outages.entityData.taskDetailsResponse.actionItems.scope.tasks.arrayOfTaskItem">
                <td>{{listItem.taskID}}</td>
                <td>{{listItem.categoryID}}</td>
                <td>{{listItem.category}}</td>
    <td>{{listItem.description}}</td>
    <td>{{listItem.status}}</td>
    <td>{{listItem.title}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

even i have tried some other options like

```js
angular.module('MyCard1App', ['ngResource']).
factory('Outage', function ($resource) {
 console.log("inside");
    return $resource('http://3.209.92.112:9090/service/readerApp/Entity/1234567880?type=Activity&appId=1&userid=test', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false}
    });
});

function IndexViewController($scope, Outage) {
 //console.log(Outage.query());
    //$scope.outages = Outage.query();
 Outage.query({}, function (data) {
  console.log(data.outages);
        $scope.outages = data.outages; 
    });
}
```

Comment: So when you open URL `http://localhost:9090/service/readerApp/Entity/1234567880?type=Activity&appId=1&userid=test` what does it show?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? I also notice that you don't have an error callback for the http request. Perhaps you should register something and see if it spits out any issues you might be having with your api call.

Comment: but you dont use the `IndexViewController` in your html. Where is the ng-controller ?

Comment: I have added the IndexViewController in body tag, and also i have found that am getting the response in IE. I found the route cause is becoz of CORS... Thanks for your ideas..

Comment: My service is running in one machine and AngularJS resource code is running in another machine, when i try to use HTTP am getting this CORS being disabled... Even i have tried running the chrome with "chrome.exe --Access-Control-Allow-Origin" but still it doesn't help...